# PyInstaller main.exe can't import PySide2.QtQuick

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyinstaller, pyside

I packaged my Qt/QML application that uses Pyside2 using pyinstaller and I run into the following error:

```
C:\WorkDir\Development\Source\App\dist\main>main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded.4bpi2020.zip\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
ImportError: could not import module 'PySide2.QtQuick'
[28752] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

In the IDE it works fine, but after I build it with PyInstaller, it throws the error above.
I use Poetry as my package manger, so maybe this is the issue and PyInstaller doesn't see or doesn't copy the needed files to the dist folder.

That being said, I see a folder name PySide2 in the `dist` folder, along with many Qt5 dlls:

[image]

Does anyone know why this might happen or have a hit as to how this issue might be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user over at Qt Forum pointed me to an [answer](https://forum.qt.io/topic/137810/pyinstaller-main-exe-can-t-import-pyside2-qtquick/3):

You can try the hidden import option. `--hidden-import=PySide2.QtQuick` for CLI or `hiddenimports=['PySide2.QtQuick']` in the spec file.

And this solved the issue.